# What did Captain America and Bucky mean respectively by "enough" during their conversation in Civil War?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In Captain America: Civil War (2016), there's a scene where Rogers, Sam and Bucky speak in what looks like an abandoned factory, after Bucky goes on a rampage due to his brain conditioning and Rogers stops him from escaping. During their conversation there, there are these exchanges:

> Bucky: "What did I do?"
>
> Rogers: "Enough."
>
> Bucky: "Oh god, I knew this would happen."

and

> *(Bucky explains the other Winter Soldiers)*
>
> Rogers: "The doctor, could he control them?"
>
> Bucky: "Enough."

What I found curious was how the "enough" in the respective exchanges were meant to be interpreted. Normally they'd be meant as "Let's not talk about this further". However I realized that the word also matched the context they were talking about: in the first exchange, Rogers could have said the word to mean "You did enough harm to give them more reasons to pursue you" (and Bucky clearly understands the implication based on his response), and in the second Bucky may have meant "The doctor could have enough control over the soldiers for him to be a big threat".

There are also reasons to interpret the word as used to cut the conversation short. In the first exchange, it might seem out of character for Rogers to outright tell his friend, whom he knows is pained about his condition, that he hurt more people and is in more trouble than he was before, so he may have wanted to just not talk about it. In the second exchange, Bucky may not have wanted to talk further and Rogers does immediately turn to Sam to continue the conversation (although Bucky does continue making comments about the subject).

If there's a clear answer to this, like a note in the published script of the movie or something, that would be great. If not, what would appear to be the more likely interpretation of the lines?

Answer (score 1):

> However I realized that the word also matched the context they were talking about: in the first exchange, Rogers could have said the word to mean "**You did enough harm to give them more reasons to pursue you**" (and Bucky clearly understands the implication based on his response), and in the second Bucky may have meant "**The doctor could have enough control over the soldiers for him to be a big threat"**.

## Your initial interpretations are correct.

There's no need in the conversation to enumerate what "enough" means since it's evident from the context.